# Choosing a Tagline

Tags: copywriting

Choosing a tag line is a crazy for a developer. We just dont understand the language enough to choose a good tagline.

We are about to release a website and a mobile app that books taxi's online. On the app you connect to your cab driver directly, without the need of a call center. I need a appropriate tagline on the home page. Please help me choose one, or suggest improvements over the existing ones.

> > Order a cab instantly, directly talk to your cab driver.
> >
> > Search and Connect to your cab driver instantly
> >
> > Still waiting for a call center to book your cab? Search for cabs yourself and connect with them directly

Comment: I'm afraid this is about creative copywriting, not UX. But anyway, I would use "Search. Tap. Go." as a tagline, and in second line: "Quick & easy taxi ordering."

Comment: Wow, sounds good. There isn't a stackoverflow group for creating copywriting. I guessed it would be appropriate for the ux forum.

Comment: This isn't the area to ask this question, as stated by Dominik. However, to help you, figure out what your unfair advantage is above your competition. What do you offer which can't be easily obtained by any of your competitors. After that, try to formulate a high level concept (such as: "Aliens is Jaws on a spaceship"). Afterwards, combine the two together and get creative :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ideas you've listed thus far seem exauhstively descriptive and borderline robotic.

A tagline should be as short as possible, and preferably not formal, or as I tried to put it, exauhstively descriptive.

The best process as far as I'm concerned is to think of what exactly makes your application useful, or sepparates you from competitors, which in this case are likely just traditional methods of getting a cab, and find a very succinct statement that gets that idea across in a very human (not so formal) way. Even if it's gramatically incorrect, it doesn't matter. The phrase should add some sort of branded personality to your product. Much like a logo would add visual recognition and connect some less tangible ideas or emotions to the product or company, a tagline should do the same but in words, rather than graphics.

The three you've mentioned seem more like a bland headline or openning to an advertisement to simply state what you do. The connection is direct enough that it doesn't add any recognizability.

Dominik Oslizlo's comment above, "Search. Tap. Go." is on target. Whether or not this is one you like personally, it works as a tagline. It's informal, not exauhstive, and connects an informal, but descriptive phrase to the product, without blandly describing exactly what it does.